# How to parse GraphQL string into an object in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I need a way to parse graphQL string to a class variable so that it becomes easy to manage and modify.
I could not find any packages that could help me for .net framework 4.5 project.

Please enlighten me with feasible solution.. Thanks in advance!

I thought of parsing the string myself using class like

```
public class GraphQL
{
    public List<Field> Query { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; } = "";
    public JObject Attributes { get; set; }
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

But proved to be too tough of a task for me..

Comment: Essentially you're asking for a GraphQL library. Parsing alone is trivial using eg JSON.NET (`var jObj=(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`) but actually implementing GraphQL functionality requires an entire library. First, don't use .NET Framework 4.5. That version reached End Of Life in 2016. That's 8 years ago, long before any GraphQL library was published. The oldest supported .NET Framework is 4.6.2 but there's no reason to use anything less than 4.8.

Comment: The best option is to use [HotChocolate on ASP.NET Core](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/get-started-with-graphql-in-net-core) It's the most popular GraphQL framework in .NET right now. It's even used by Microsoft's [Azure Data API Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-api-builder/overview-to-data-api-builder?tabs=azure-sql) which, despite its name, doesn't require Azure.